# Why doesn't 'this' keyword work in following html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an alert with "button text"

this doesn't work:

```
<button onclick="fun()">button text</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function fun(){
        alert($(this).html()); //I've also tried $(this).val() and $(this).text()
    }
</script>
```

but following works fine:

```
<script>
    function fun(){
        alert("some plain text");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please take a look at my answer - it thoroughly answers your query and addresses why the other answers "work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize you've already accepted an answer, but none of the answers you received addressed your question. Please consider the following:

The HTML attribute for the `on-` type handlers were designed from the beginning to take raw JavaScript code and wrap that code into a function. That function is provided with the event object and the context set to the keyword `this` as the element receiving the event. So the first button in my solution below is the proper way to accomplish what you were attempting to do.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value

The same can be accomplished by setting the DOM Element's `on-` event *property* to the function name. This is seen in the second button example. Note that when the DOM property is used, the event is passed and the context set the DOM element too.

Now, the reason something like `onclick="fun(this)"` and its variants work in these answers, is because that is being wrapped inside a function which is executed with the `this` keyword set the context of the DOM element (just as described above). So it is a function calling a function and passing the current context - and an anti-pattern.

That should really answer your question.

```js
document.querySelector('#otherButton').onclick = fun;

function fun() {
  alert($(this).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="alert($(this).html());">button text</button>
<button id="otherButton">other button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful

Answer (score 2):

The `this` you're trying to log is the `Window` object, on which you can't use `innerHTML`. Instead, pass the context of the `button` element.

```js
function fun(context) {
  alert($(context).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="fun(this)">button text</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
<button onclick="fun(this)">button text</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function fun(myButton){
        alert($(myButton).html()); //I've also tried $(this).val() and $(this).text()
    }
</script>
```

Within `fun`, `this` will not be your button, because `fun` is not called on the button.

The following also works:

```
<button onclick="fun.apply(this)">button text</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function fun(){
        alert($(this).html()); //I've also tried $(this).val() and $(this).text()
    }
</script>
```

This code causes `this` to be defined in the manner you tried to use it.

Comment: true - but doesn't even attempt to answer the question - Why doesn't the other work.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I was still in the middle of adding more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `fun()` as a free function but not as a method. Being called as a function the `fun()` receives `this` set to global namespace.

In order to call `fun` with `this` set to what you want you shall be specific, for example like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="fun.call(this)">button text</button>

<script>
    function fun(){
        alert($(this).html()); //I've also tried $(this).val() and $(this).text()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a native js event handler does not give the `this` context for jquery. The dom element that you clicked on is available through

```
function fun (e) {
  let el = e.target // currentTarget, etc.
}
```